# Difference between the two code blocks in Javascript when a new line is entered

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What is happening in both the cases and why is the output changing when the curly braces are placed on a new line. I'm not aware of this concept. Please explain.

Code Segment 1:

```
(function(){
    return {
        a : 1
    }
})();

# Output
{a: 1}
```

Code Segment 2:

```
(function(){
    return 
    {
        a : 1
    }
})();

# Output 
undefined
```

Why isn't the object returned in second scenario? I just added a newline character.

Comment: @Nicolas yes it does! Thanks!

Comment: Also relevant: [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Comment: @VLAZ  Thanks for the response!